# JComboBox does not trigger actionPerformed() when there is an exception on the AWT-EventQueue-0 thread

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, actionlistener, jcombobox

```
  //This is my test class 
  Public class crazySwing extends JFrame {
    private DefaultListModel model;
    public crazySwing() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        Vector v= new Vector();
        v.add(1);
        v.add(2);
        //comboxbox with 2 items  
        JComboBox test  = new JComboBox(v);

        test.addActionListener(new ClickAction());

        createLayout(test);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        JPanel pane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl);

        pane.setToolTipText("Content pane");        

        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[0])
                .addGap(200)
        );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[0])
                .addGap(120)
        );



        pack();        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                crazySwing ex = new crazySwing();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

private class ClickAction extends AbstractAction {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

           System.out.println("testing on exception");
           //This will trigger a null Pointer exception
           List test = null;
           test.get(0);
        }
    }        
}
```

Hi guys, I'm working on a Java rich client and I encountered the above symptom.
When the JComboBox is clicked for the first time, a null pointer exception will be thrown by the code and then, when I try clicking on the JComboxBox again, actionPerformed() is not triggered.

I have tried it on a JButton but it won't happen to a JButton.

This is not a question about how to resolve a NPE. Kindly read the posting title.

Comment: @alex2410, I delibrately put in the code List test = null; test.get(0) to get a NullPointerEx. I except JComboBox to still trigger actionPerformed() after it encountered a NullPointerEx for the first time.

Comment: You shoud read about [exceptions in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html).

Comment: @DanialChan really strange behaviour. Try to use `ItemListener` instead of `ActionListener` it works as you expected.

Comment: @alex2410..cheers buddy!!

Comment: Seems that very old [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-5047320?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab)

Comment: affected version was 1.4.2 and I'm using 1.7...hmmmm

Comment: It still here ;) because `Resolution: Not an Issue`